# DVI KVM switch for a 30" monitor?

Tags: display, kvm-switch

I have two machines to which I would like to attach a Dell 30" monitor via a KVM switch. Most KVM switches don't support the maximum resolution of the monitor (2550x1600). The only solution I have been able to find is the [Belkin Flip](http://www.belkin.com/flip/) that on a good day leaves strange artifacts in the signal, and at worst is useless.

Is there a better KVM switch than the Flip for large displays?

Comment: While [technically off topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3587/update-the-faq-to-disallow-any-product-recommendation-questions), the hardware used is quite superuser-y and should make this [an uncommon problem](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions) we could tolerate.

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence in the question -- thanks!

Comment: Would it work to use two different inputs on the monitor (Dell's monitors usually have at least 2 DVI ports, as well as others)? You could use a normal KVM switch for the keyboard and mouse, then switch the display input manually.

Comment: Most DVI KVMs seem to support 2560x1600. Belkin even makes a bunch ([Belkin Advanced Secure DVI-I KVM Switch](http://www.belkin.com/kvm/secure/)), you just have to plan on going outside of their current desktop/consumer offerings, and spending a bit more on it.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself, but the only two feedback entries on this [STARTECH SV431DVIUAHR](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707176) KVM are a full 5 stars and they confirm it works at 2550x1600 on two different 30" monitors.  If you don't like that one, Newegg's advanced search on KVM's let you filter on resolution.  They currently list 18 KVMs that appear to support resolutions >= 2550x1600.

Good luck.